# Subscribe to input valuechanges and request to spotify

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I am trying to get data from spotify api using Observables in Angular 2 in the below code.

I want to subscribe to the input valuechanges event which in turn sends a request to spotify with the search term entered in.

I am new to Observables and really having a hard time with this whole nested callback/observables thing. Would appreciate if someone get provide code on how i can properly subscribe to an input box and display spotify results as a user types.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'spotify-search',
  template: `
    <h1>Spotify Search</h1>
    <input 
        class="form-control"
      [formControl]="searchBox" 
      placeholder="Search Spotify artist" />

    <div *ngFor=" let artists of results | async"> 
        {{ artists.name }} -- Followers {{artists.followers.total}} -- Popularity {{ artists.popularity }}        
    </div>
  `
})
export class SpotifySearchComponent {

  private searchBox = new FormControl();

  constructor(private _http: Http){

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {  
    var keyups = this.searchBox
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(200)
        .map(searchTerm => {
            return this.getResults(searchTerm);           
        });

    var subscription = keyups.subscribe(res => console.log(res));       
  }

  getResults(searchTerm){           
    return this._http.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=' + searchTerm + '&type=artist')
      .map(response => {
            response.json();                                    
      }, error => console.log('Could not load artists'));            
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your code you missed implementation of the interface "AfterViewInit"

```
export class SpotifySearchComponent implements AfterViewInit {...
```